How to set up a constructor when you don't know which args for which variable will be passed
In my class I have a few settings; let's call them: setting1, setting2, setting3. I want to pass an argument for setting1 and setting3 in the constructor without modifying setting2 or passing all 3 of them as an argument.
I have seen someone do this by using a dictionary and reading the key and then then changing the setting based on the value but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

How can you "modify" setting2 in the constructor?  If it's a constructor, there is no previous value to modify.  Do you have default values for all three?  C# allows named arguments.  You can say Object(setting1: 3, setting3: 4).

The constructor could take those three arguments (or an object with three properties) and check if each setting is not null before using it.

Class c1 = new(setting1: "AA", setting3: "CC");
Class c2 = new(setting2: "BB");

class Class(
    string setting1 = "A",
    string setting2 = "B",
    string setting3 = "C")
{
    public string setting1 = setting1;
    public string setting2 = setting2;
    public string setting3 = setting3;
}

If settings are classes:
Class c1 = new(setting1: new("AA"), setting3: new("CC"));
Class c2 = new(setting2: new("BB"));

class Class(
    Setting1 setting1 = default!,
    Setting2 setting2 = default!,
    Setting3 setting3 = default!)
{
    public Setting1 setting1 = setting1 ?? Setting1.Default;
    public Setting2 setting2 = setting2 ?? Setting2.Default;
    public Setting3 setting3 = setting3 ?? Setting3.Default;
}

class Setting1(string s1)
{
    public string s1 = s1;
    public static readonly Setting1 Default = new("A");
}

class Setting2(string s2)
{
    public string s2 = s2;
    public static readonly Setting2 Default = new("B");
}

class Setting3(string s3)
{
    public string s3 = s3;
    public static readonly Setting3 Default = new("C");
}

